# To echo PWD in Vim's : -mode to the document

Tags: command-line, vim

I would like to insert my current PATH effectively onto my document.

I run unsuccesfully

```
:echo $PWD
```

and

```
:pwd
```

**How can you insert your current PATH in the VIM -document on your your document?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
:r ! pwd
```

Comment: What does r stands for?

Comment: Read, I believe.

Comment: Yes.  "Read from command `pwd` into the current buffer."

Answer (score 4):

This may be more platform independent:

```
put=getcwd()
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Windows!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:.!pwd` in vim's normal mode.